# How to get a collection with linq but leave out some entities from a nested collection?

Tags: c#, linq

I have this linq:

```
List<Group> groups = 
   context.Groups.Where(group => group.Station.Id == stationId).ToList();
```

But i'm getting too many users for the groups.

I want to incorporate this:

```
group.Users.Where(u => u.Account.IsActive == true)
```

But I cant fit it anywhere without getting a error.

Help much appreciated after trying so many things without getting it right.

UPDATE:

Its only syntax errors I got from trying the All() and other functions.. I don't seem to have had such complicated quires with linq before..

UPDATE:

```
 List<Group> groups = context.Groups.Where(group => 
    group.Station.Id == stationId && 
    group.Users.Where(u => u.Account.IsActive == true)).ToList();
```

The error:

> Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'

Comment: *"without getting a error"*  What error did you get?   When you compiled it or ran it?  Did you understand the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<Group> groups = context.Groups
                            .Where(group => group.Station.Id == stationId 
                                            && group.Users.Where(u => u.Account.IsActive == true).Count() > 0).ToList();
```

You should compare it with count. That was the error.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this. [Filtering of related entities](http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/1015345-allow-filtering-for-include-extension-method) is not implemented yet. Related entities can be loaded only all at once.

Thus you cannot remove inactive users from groups or filter them, you should create new groups with only active users. It's not possible to do on server side if you are using Entity Framework (you'll see *The entity or complex type 'Group' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query*). But you can return anonymous objects with required data:

```
var groups = from g in context.Groups
             where g.Station.Id == stationId
             select new {
                Id = g.Id,
                ActiveUsers = g.Users.Where(u => u.Account.IsActive)
             };
```

Comment: No I dont think i'm mutating anything.. Its only a restriction on the users pulled

Comment: @Servy he is trying to mutate group's list of users - he want to remove inactive users from result

Comment: @MichaelWinther unfortunately there is no option for restrictions on the pulled users - only all users can be pulled, so further 'restriction' is chaging of result

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Okay thanks. So what is then the best practices? To iterate (Which right now give problems for me because I cannot remove any objects when iterating, im trying to keep track of the users and after iterating, im removing), or would it be to make a sql2entities like you tried? Its not working, and cant get it to work right now.. just wanna try some things before saying I cant get it to work..

Comment: @MichaelWinther I have re-phrased answer (it looks like you don't modify related entities, but they are currently loaded all at once, so internally restriction should be modification) and added link on feature you should wait for. Sorry, I don't understand what you have tried. Sample above with anonymous object works fine

Comment: Okay got it thx. About the error, its underlining the "select" and is saying: 

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Model.Models.Group>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) Also I have methods depending on the structure of the object returned (List<Group> with a ISet<User>)i'm sending right now.. its seams you are changing that for users right?

Comment: @MichaelWinther this query return anonymous objects, not Group entities. Also its not List - its Queryable. Thats why you see error. Make sure you are using `var` keyword for query type definition. If you need to use `Group` entities, you can execute query and manually create Group entities on client side

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy thanks for your help. I still haven't got it. I updated my question with the error.

Comment: @MichaelWinther please don't modify original question. It should contain your original attempt to solve problem. If you are trying some of suggestions, then write comments to appropriate answer. Regarding your problem - you are assigning `g.Users.Where(u => u.Account.IsActive)` to `Group.Users` which have different types. You should put filtered users collection to collection of appropriate type. I rolled back your last edit

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy I made it work with a HashSet in the end. Thanks